# Complex numbers and subset properties

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, trigonometry, complex-numbers, contest-math

> Let $A$ be the set $A = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| = r\},$ where $r \in \mathbb{R}, r > 0$.
>
> **(a)** Prove that there exist $a, b \in A$, $a \neq b$, such that $a + b \in A$.
>
> **(b)** Find the natural number values $n \geq 2$ for which there exists a subset $S$ of $A$ with $|S|=n$, such that $u + v \in A$ for any $u, v \in S$, $u \neq v$.

My approach:
For part **(a)**, we write $a = r(\cos x + i\sin x)$ and $b = r(\cos y + i\sin y)$. Then, we get
$$
a + b = 2r\cos\Bigl(\frac{x-y}{2}\Bigr) \, 
\biggl( \cos\Bigl(\frac{x+y}{2}\Bigr) 
+ i\sin\Bigl(\frac{x+y}{2}\Bigr) \biggr).
$$

Now, we try to find $x$ and $y$ when $r = 1$. We can assume $r = 1$ since we need to find at least one $(a, b)$ that exists. Taking the modulus of $a + b$, we get
$$
\cos\Bigl(\frac{x-y}{2}\Bigr) = \frac{1}{2}\, 
$$
which which means $x-y = \pm\frac{2\pi}{3}$ or $\pm\frac{4\pi}{3}$.

For part **(b)**, we have to prove that $n$ can only be $2$ or $3$. How do we prove that for $n \geq 4$ we get a contradiction? I need help completing my solution.

Comment: Presumably, you want to solve 
$$
\cos\frac{x-y}{2} = \frac12, 
$$
which only has $2$ solutions for $x-y$ on the unit circle. Note that $+\frac{2\pi}{3}$ is coterminal to $-\frac{4\pi}{3}$, and also $-\frac{2\pi}{3}$ is coterminal to $\frac{4\pi}{3}$, so the set of four values for $x-y$ collapses to $2$.

Comment: **Hint** for part (b): For $n=3$ the set $S \neq A$, but for $n = 2$ we have $S = A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we have a set $S\subset A$ with $|S|>1$ such that $a+b\in A$ for all distinct $a,b\in S$. Fix $a_0\in S$ and replace $S$ with $T=\{a/a_0:a\in S\}$. Note that $T\subset \{z:|z|=1\}$, since $|a/a_0|=r/r=1$ for all $a\in S$. Also, $a+b\in \{z:|z|=1\}$ for all distinct $a,b\in T$, since for such $a,b$, we have $a=a'/a_0$ and $b=b'/a_0$ for distinct $a',b'\in S$ and $$|a+b|=\frac{|a'+b'|}{|a_0|}=r/r=1.$$  Moreover, $a\mapsto a/a_0$ is an injection, so $|S|=|T|$.

Thus it suffices to consider the case $r=1$ and $1\in S$. Let $A=\{z:|z|=1\}$.

Suppose $1\neq x+iy\in S$. Then since $x+iy\in S\subset A$, $y^2=1-x^2$. Since $1+x+iy\in A$, $$(1+x)^2+y^2=1,$$ so $$1=1+2x+x^2+y^2=1+2x+x^2+1-x^2=1+2x+1.$$ So $2x=-1$ and $x=-1/2$. We obtain $y=\pm \sqrt{3}/{2}$.

Comment: How do we prove that n can only be 2 and 3?

Comment: We just proved that. If $r=1$ and $1\in S$, the only two other points which could possibly be in $S$ are $-1/2+\sqrt{3}/2$ and $-1/2-\sqrt{3}{2}$.

Comment: Don’t we have to write what happens for n>=4 to show that indeed only 2 and 3 work?

Comment: No. We showed that any set having the desired property has at most three points.

Comment: This $a\mapsto a/a_0$ is an injection, so $|S|=|T|$ allows us to only look at the case where r=1?

Comment: Yes. But if you don't like that, fix distinct $a,b\in S$ and write $a=a\cdot 1$ and $b=a\cdot (x+iy)$. Then $$r^2=|b|^2=|a^2|(x^2+y^2)=r^2(x^2+y^2),$$ so $x^2+y^2=1$. And $$r^2=|a+b|^2=|a^2|((1+x)^2+y^2)=r^2((1+x)^2+y^2).$$ Solving this still yields $x=-1/2$, $y=\pm \sqrt{3}/2$, and the only other two points which could possibly be in $S$ besides $a$ are $$a\Bigl(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\Bigr)$$ and $$a\Bigl(\frac{-1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\Bigr).$$

Comment: I thought about considering S={a,b,c,d| |z|=r} and then from (a) we know that the sum of every two distinct numbers is in S and I tried obtaining a contradiction

Comment: That also works. My recommendation would be to consider $\beta = b/a$, $\gamma=c/a$, and $\delta=d/a$. Then the numbers $1,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ each lie in the unit circle, and the sum of any two of these numbers also lie in the unit circle. Write $\beta=x_1+iy_1$, $\gamma=x_2+iy_2$, and $\delta=x_3+iy_3$ and play around (somewhat like I did above) with the expressions $(1+x_j)^2+y_j^2=1$. You'll "run out" of points before getting through the fourth one.

Comment: If we prove that for n=4 we get a contradiction how do we extend the contradiction for n=5,6,7,8,9… ? And why would we consider beta=b/a and the others in this form?

Comment: If you prove that there cannot be a set $S$ with $|S|=4$ having the property in the question, then if $|S|>4$ has the property in the question, we can choose a subset $T$ of $S$ with $|T|=4$, and $T$ will still have the property. That contradicts the $n=4$ case.

Comment: So that means it suficient to prove that n=4 gives us a contradiction, for my proof. But for your proof we don’t have to do this, correct?

Comment: That's correct. Let's say a set $S\subset \mathbb{C}$ has property $P$ if  for some $r>0$, $|z|=r$ for all $z\in S$ and $|z_1+z_2|=r$ for all distinct $z_1,z_2\in S$. My proof was of the form "Any set $S$ with property $P$ has $|S|\leqslant 3$". Your method proves the contrapositive: "If $|S|>3$, then $S$ does not have property $P$." These are logically equivalent.

Comment: Now I get it. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! To answer your question about why I considered $a/a=1$, $b/a$, etc., I just realized that for the equalities $|a|=|b|=|a+b|$, it's not really $a,b$ that matter, but the angle between them. That's what $b/a$ is capturing. However, we could proceed without this. Write $a=x+iy$ and $b=p+iq$. Then $$r^2=x^2+y^2=p^2+q^2=(x+p)^2+(y+q)^2.$$ If you play around with this, you still find that $$b=a\Bigl(-\frac{1}{2}\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\Bigr).$$

Comment: If we include a third number $c$ such that $|c|=|a+c|$, then the same calculation gives that $c$ must also satisfy $$c=a\Bigl(-\frac{1}{2}\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\Bigr).$$ Therefore $\{b,c\}=\{-\frac{1}{2}\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\},$$ and there can't be a fourth point.

Answer (score 2):

The claim in (b) follows more or less immediately from your argument for (a): You've shown that given a point $z \in A$, any other point in $A$ must be an unsigned angle $\frac{2 \pi}{3}$ from that point, and there are only $2$ such points (namely, $e^{\pm 2 \pi i / 3} z$).

We can actually give a stronger result: Given a subset $S \subset A$ of $n := |S| \geq 2$ points, the Pigeonhole Principle implies that there are two points $a, b \in S$ such that the angle $\theta$ between $a$ and $b$ is at most $\frac{2 \pi}{n}$. Using that $\cos$ is decreasing on $[0, \pi]$ and the Law of Cosines gives a lower bound on $|a + b|$. We have
$$|a + b|^2 = |a|^2 + 2 |a| |b| \cos \theta + |b|^2 = 2 r^2 (1 + \cos \theta) \geq 2 r^2 \left(1 + \cos \frac{2\pi}n\right),$$ hence
$$|a + b| \geq r \sqrt{2 \left(1 + \cos \frac{2\pi}n\right)} = 2 r \cos \frac{\pi}{n}.$$

In particular, if $n \geq 4$, then $|a + b| \geq \sqrt{2} r > r$, and hence $a + b \not\in A$. Satisfyingly, if $n = 5$, there are points $a, b \in S$ such that $|a + b| \geq \phi r$, where $\phi$ denotes the Golden Ratio.

Equality (for $n \geq 3$) holds iff $S$ consists of the vertices of a regular polygon.

Comment: How does this prove that the only values taken by n are 2 and 3 and for n>=4 we get a contradiction?

Comment: @math.enthusiast9 If $n \geq 4$, then $\cos \frac{\pi}{n} \geq \cos \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, so there are points $a, b \in S$ such that $|a + b| \geq \sqrt{2} r.$ In particular, $|a + b| \neq r$, so $a + b \not\in A$.